# How to omit and delete part of the value from an object in TypeScript correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

The `useHider` function was used to hide some values from an object with corret type, like if I use `const res = useHider({ id: 1, title: "hi"}, "id")`, it will come back with `{ title: "hi" }` only, and when I try to use `res.id`, it will come with error in TypeScript.

The `hideQueryResult` function allow me to hide `createdAt`, `updatedAt` and `deletedAt` by default, or I can add some params to hide more values from an object.

```js
const useHider = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keysToHide: K[]) => {
    let res = obj;

    keysToHide.forEach((key) => {
        delete res[key];
    });

    return res as Omit<T, K>;
};

const hideQueryResult = <T, K extends keyof T>(
    query: T,
    keysToHide: K[] = [],
) => {
    const at = ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"] as K[];
    const allKeysToHide = [...keysToHide, ...at];
    const res = useHider(query, allKeysToHide);
    return res;
};
```

But when I try to use `hideQueryResult` to hide some values, it do not work as I expected.

```js
const source = {
    id: "01ABC",
    title: "123",
    createdAt: "ABC",
    updatedAt: "ABC",
    deletedAt: "ABC",
};

const res1 = useHider(source, ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"]);

console.log(res1.id); // success (expected)
console.log(res1.createdAt); // failed (expected)

const res2 = hideQueryResult(source);

console.log(res2.id); // failed (not expected)

const res3 = hideQueryResult(source, ["id"]);

console.log(res3.createdAt); // success (not expected)
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: useHider(source, [stuff]) modifies `source` so the next time you use source it’s missing a bunch of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first make a shallow copy from the `obj`. because if you don't, the `res` will be reference to `obj`. so, if you try to delete a property from `res`, it will actually delete from `obj`. but with this syntax (`{...obj}`) you can make a shallow copy and delete/add the properties you want.

```
const useHider = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keysToHide: K[]) => {
    let res = {...obj}; // edited line

    keysToHide.forEach((key) => {
        delete res[key];
    });

    return res as Omit<T, K>;
};
```

**note:** shallow copy will only copy the first keys and values, the values may still refer to the main values. so:

```
const obj = { 
    name: "John", 
    data: {
        age: 10
    }
}

const clone = {...obj}

clone.username = "Alex"
console.log(obj.username) // John

clone.data.age = 20
console.log(obj.data.age) // 20

clone.data = null
console.log(obj.data) // { age: 20 }
```

Now, to solve the type issues. you need to tell the typescript that the object that goes to the `useHider` through `hideQueryResult` can have those 3 fields. and then give it a default value, so when we don't give the 2nd argument, typescript will not infer every single key automatically and instead use the `never` type as the default value which means there is not any set data.

```
const fieldsToRemove = ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"] as const // `const` makes it readonly and type-friendly

const hideQueryResult = <T, K extends keyof T = never>( // `never` means no data is set
    query: T,
    keysToHide: K[] = [],
) => {
    const res = useHider(
        query as T & Record<typeof fieldsToRemove[number], unknown>, // Record makes an object type. (first arg is the keys and 2nd arg is the value type)
        [...fieldsToRemove, ...keysToHide]
    );
    return res;
};
```

Comment: But how to solve the issue that TypeScript omit the wrong value?

Comment: @Alpheus my bad, completely forgot the 2nd issue :) now I added the solution. feel free to test each new syntax and read the documentation to get more details about each one. or ask here and I will help

Answer (score 0):

First off, your use Hider function is modifying the original object because objects in JavaScript are passed by reference. So when you're doing delete res[key];, you're actually deleting the property from the original object. That's a no-no for our tea party!

Let's make a shallow copy of the object first

```
const useHider = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keysToHide: K[]) => {
let res = { ...obj }; // Spread the object into a new one

keysToHide.forEach((key) => {
    delete res[key];
});

return res as Omit<T, K>;
};
```

Now, for the hideQueryResult function, the issue is with the spread of keysToHide and at. When you spread them into allKeysToHide, TypeScript loses track of the exact keys you're omitting. Instead, let's concatenate them:

```
const hideQueryResult = <T, K extends keyof T>(
query: T,
keysToHide: K[] = [],
) => {
const at: K[] = ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"] as any;
const allKeysToHide = keysToHide.concat(at);
const res = useHider(query, allKeysToHide);
return res;
};
```

maybe that will help?

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. I'll look at it again.